# Global Keyboard Shortcuts Broken in 14.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.04

I've just upgraded my distribution from 13.10 to 14.04, which seems to have broken global keyboard shortcuts.

They are still present in the "Keyboard settings" as before. Although media keys are affected, so are other global shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for Terminal. Other keyboard shortcuts work at an application level still, however.

I am also currently using Gnome Shell as my desktop environment, although the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> shortcut for shell commands still seems to work.

Does anyone know of how this could have been caused?

Answer (score 3):

It seams to be a bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1224732

On my laptop, they are two ways to bypass :

1. my custom shortcut works if I use a more simple key binding. For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> does not work, but <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works.
2. use an alternative way to create a custom command with the CompizConfig Settings Manager launched with `ccsm` > Commands. Then create your key binding.

Remark in the both solution, my key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> doest not work, but <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> works. I think some key binding can not be used anymore.

Comment: Using Compiz's "Commands" worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with Ubuntu 14.04, got fixed after forcibly upgrading gnome from 3.10 (stable) to 3.12 (staging)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
# reboot
```

By the time you're reading this 3.12 might be the stable version, so check first:

```
gnome-shell --version
#=> GNOME Shell 3.12.2
```

Comment: I tried to check my gnome-shell version with the latter command, but got `The program 'gnome-shell' is currently not installed.` Could that really be the case? I'm on a regular install of Ubuntu 14.04.